# R Shiny update DT cell based on reactivity within same table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to update cells in a datatable object (within Shiny) depending on a selection done in the same table, different column.
The Shiny input ID is registered and it's possible to access its value. However replacing data within the DT using its proxy does not seem to work (the column ANIMAL should change depending on column GROUP).
Anyone has an idea on how this could be achieved?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# JS function to render selectize input in DT object
js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  $('#selectNR').selectize()",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Reactivity within table: no response."),
  fluidRow(
    DTOutput(outputId = "tableNR"),
    verbatimTextOutput('selectedGroupNR')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  getData <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      GROUP = '<select id="selectNR" class="form-control">
                       <option value="A" selected>A</option>
                       <option value="B">B</option>
                       <option value="C">C</option>
                    </select>',
      ANIMAL = 'Dog',
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$tableNR <- renderDT({
    datatable(data = isolate(getData()),
              selection = "none",
              escape = FALSE,
              rownames = TRUE,
              options =
                list(dom = 't',
                     initComplete = JS(js),
                     preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                     drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                ))
  })
  # Set up proxy to update table when new selection is done.
  proxyNR <- dataTableProxy('tableNR')
  observeEvent(input$selectNR, {
    toReplace <- getData()
    toReplace$ANIMAL <- switch(input$selectNR,
                               'A' = 'Dog',
                               'B' = 'Cat',
                               'C' = 'Fish')
    DT::replaceData(proxyNR, toReplace, resetPaging = TRUE)
  })
  # As a check
  output$selectedGroupNR <- renderPrint({
    paste0('Selected group = ', input$selectNR)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That can't work. First , `.selectize` is not found because you don't have a selectize input in your app. Secondly, when you replace the data, you don't replace the selector, and it will reset to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. You have to update the `<select>` as well.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Reactivity within table: no response."),
  fluidRow(
    DTOutput(outputId = "tableNR"),
    verbatimTextOutput('selectedGroupNR')
  )
)

group <- function(letter){
  paste0(
    '<select id="selectNR" class="form-control">',
    ifelse(letter == "A", 
           '<option value="A" selected>A</option>',
           '<option value="A">A</option>'),
    ifelse(letter == "B", 
           '<option value="B" selected>B</option>',
           '<option value="B">B</option>'),
    ifelse(letter == "C", 
           '<option value="C" selected>C</option>',
           '<option value="C">C</option>'),
    '</select>'
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  getData <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      GROUP = '<select id="selectNR" class="form-control">
                       <option value="A">A</option>
                       <option value="B">B</option>
                       <option value="C">C</option>
                    </select>',
      ANIMAL = 'Dog',
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$tableNR <- renderDT({
    datatable(data = isolate(getData()),
              selection = "none",
              escape = FALSE,
              rownames = TRUE,
              options =
                list(dom = 't',
                     preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                     drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                ))
  })
  # Set up proxy to update table when new selection is done.
  proxyNR <- dataTableProxy('tableNR')
  observeEvent(input$selectNR, {
    toReplace <- getData()
    toReplace$GROUP <- group(input$selectNR)
    toReplace$ANIMAL <- switch(input$selectNR,
                               'A' = 'Dog',
                               'B' = 'Cat',
                               'C' = 'Fish')
    replaceData(proxyNR, toReplace, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  # As a check
  output$selectedGroupNR <- renderPrint({
    paste0('Selected group = ', input$selectNR)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```